# Get a list of devices from Notification Hub

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-notificationhub

I am using Azure Notification Hubs to manage my device registrations.

I am using Azure Mobile Services to push notification request to Notification Hub.

Using tags, I am able to use notification hub to broadcast sender's message to a group of recipients.

My new requirement is, I want sender to be able to send notification to a particular device that belongs to a particular tag. Which means I need a way for sender to list all devices that is registered to, say... "football" tag, have sender choose which device to send to, and tell Notification Hub to send notification to that device.

How do I achieve that? I will need to write an api that returns all devices that belong to a certain tag to the sender right?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn369455.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Notification Hubs allows users to extract all registrations associated with a single device. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223274.aspx, that should help.